# How can I get the machine name of a taxonomy term knowing its tid?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, database

Is there any table in the database that shows the relationship between vocabulary and taxonomy, or is there any way to find out the vocabulary name of a particular taxonomy from its tid?

Answer (score 3):

The table `taxonomy_term_data` lists the terms, and `taxonomy_vocabulary` lists the vocabularies.

In the table `taxonomy_term_data`, the term string is found in the `name` field. The field `vid` identifies the vocabulary assocaiated with the term. And the field `tid` is the numeric taxonomy id.

So you can look up the relationship between the term `name`, `tid` and `vid` directly from the this table.

Then, to determine the vocabulary name string associated with the term, you need to left join the `taxonomy_vocabulary.name` field, where `taxonomy_vocabulary.vid` = `taxonomy_term_data.vid`.

Answer (score 3):

Using the API would be preferable to going into the database directly as you can take advantage of caching properly, and keep a more structured code base at the same time:

```
$term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
$vocab = taxonomy_vocabulary_load($term->vid);
$machine_name = $vocab->machine_name;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have the taxonomy term ID, it is enough you call [taxonomy_term_load()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_load/7).

```
$term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
$vocabulary_name = $term->vocabulary_machine_name;
```

Using the Devel module, you can notice the object returned from `taxonomy_term_load()` contains the following fields.

[image: screenshot]

With Drupal 8, each entity has its own PHP class, contrary to previous Drupal versions where each entity instance is a `stdClass` object.

In Drupal 7, if you don't have a taxonomy term ID, and you want to load all the taxonomy terms, you should use the [EntityFieldQuery](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7) class; see [How to use EntityFieldQuery](http://drupal.org/node/1343708). In Drupal 8, [entity_load_multiple_by_properties()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!entity.inc/function/entity_load_multiple_by_properties/8) is the function you should use.

Comment: Indeed, [TaxonomyTermController::buildQuery()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/TaxonomyTermController%3A%3AbuildQuery/7) joins in the vocab table to get that value when you use `taxonomy_term_load()`. You learn something new every day :)

Comment: So; how would you load the machine_name in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 0):

With D8 something like [this](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2021-07-19/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-taxonomy).

```
$parameters = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameters()->all();
if (isset($parameters['taxonomy_term'])) {
  $term = $parameters['taxonomy_term'];  
  $vid = $term->bundle();
  $vocabulary = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_vocabulary')->load($vid);
  $vocabulary_label = $vocabulary->label();
}
```

Comment: The OP asked for the machine name of the vocabulary, not the label. So the correct answer would be the `$vid` I guess.